# How to add more than one navigation bar item on the same side of the bar in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

when using UIKit we can add more than one navigation bar item on leading side or trailing side, but how to do that in swiftUI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put them in a `HStack` like so:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("My View")
                .navigationBarTitle("My View")
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                    HStack {
                        Button("Button1") {
                            // action
                        }

                        Button("Button2") {
                            // action
                        }
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `.navigationBarItems(leading:trailing:)` will be deprecated in a future version of iOS according to apple. One should use .toolbar(_:) instead for adding navigation bar items.

Here is a quick example for adding two trailing items:

```
.toolbar {
            
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button("Item1") {

        }
    }
            
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button("Item2") {
                   
        }
    }
            
}
```